# top 10 comments of each messages

Tags: database, mysql, left-join, join

I have two tables. One for messages and one for comments. For each entry in messages table there will be multiple records in comments table. 
Now I want to select the top 5 messages and top 10 comments for each message.
My table structure is

### Messages

MID        Message

1         msg 1

2         msg 2

### Comments

CID   MID   Comment   Date

1     1     Cmnt1     date 1

2     1     Cmnt2     date 2

3     1     Cmnt3     date 3

4     2     Cmnt4     date 4

5     2     Cmnt5     date 5

Thanks in Advance

-Arun

Comment: What do you mean by top? The first?

Comment: Please see edit if that was at least a bit helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is a bit vague. However, assuming you have a field indicating your criteria for being "top", e.g. votes:

For MySQL you can use a select statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments
JOIN messages ON comments.mid = messages.mid
WHERE messages.mid = 1    
ORDER BY comments.topvotes DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This query would give you the top 10 voted comments for message 1.

A more complex query for getting the comments sorted for the top five messages:

```
SELECT comments.cid
FROM comments
JOIN messages ON comments.mid = messages.mid
WHERE comments.mid IN(
        SELECT messages.mid
        FROM messages
        ORDER BY messages.votes DESC
        LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY messages.mid, comments.votes DESC;
```

But I can't quite figure out, how to limit this to the 10 top comments. I would use a cursor, but I've been doing too much PLSQL on Oracle lately anyway. So if anyone got a good solution how to express that in a single select with a subquery, please shoot...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Top means last entries. That is last five messages and last 10 comments for each messages. Hope its clear now